# How to create threaded list in CakePHP?

Tags: list, cakephp, multithreading

I create table: id, name, thread_id
The mainly thread has thread_id = 0, but their children has theard_id = id of parent, and how is the best and simplest solution to create list with children, and looks like:

1. Category 1
   Product 1
   Product 2
2. Category 2
   Product 3
   etc...

Maybe You have better solution for such a list?

Sorry, for my english:)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the easiest way may be to use Cake's own `TreeBehavior`. More on that at http://book.cakephp.org/view/91/Tree. I've never used it personally, but have heard good things. It should provide all of the tools (and instruction) you need.

Comment: I know this, and I used, but Tree Behavior is for unlimited levels, but, I want create the most simplest tree, only with 2 levels (parent and childrens). Tree behavior in this moment, will be "too big":)
I know there is in CakePHP find('threaded'), but I can't understood this...

Comment: Sounds like you might be after this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/812/find-threaded. I don't know the details, but it appears to use a hybrid of the nested set and adjacency list models.

Answer (score 1):

One of easiest and efficient is to use Tree behavior as proposed by kicaj-pl. 
But I suggest you to consider [MultiTree Behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/multitree-behavior). It's also using nested tree database model but allows you to create many trees with different root_id and independent left and right values (so update of one tree doesn't update any other).

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I found this sentence: When You use find('threaded') you have to field 'parent_id' for creating structure like tree...
All works fine!

Thanks for replies, bye!

Answer (score 0):

Try the MPPT logic for It. For that you need 3 fields in your database table viz parent_id , lft , rght. And to implement it using CakePHP, CakePHP already provided the function for it for that please refer http://book.cakephp.org/view/228/Basic-Usage :)

Answer (score 0):

1.First, your model must use "Tree" behaviour in model file (Modelname.php - in my case Post.php)

```
public $actsAs = array('Tree');
```

2.Next you need to retrieve threaded results and pass them to a view (ModelnamesController.php - in my case PostsController.php).

```
    $posts = $this->Post->find('threaded');
    $this->set('posts', $posts);
```

3.Finally, here's a template you can use, that renders infinitely threaded list for the above results

```
<div id="posts_navi">

    <? function renderPosts($postsArray, $tmpModel){
        //set return for the first time
        if(!isset($return)){ $return = ""; }

        $return .= '<ul>';
        //create list
        foreach ($postsArray as $post){

                $return .= '<li>';
                if($post['Post']['content'] != null){
                    $return .= $tmpModel->link($post['Post']['title'], array('action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id']),array('escape'=>false));
                }else{
                    $return .= $post['Post']['title'];
                }

                //if post has children, go deeper
                if(!empty($post['children'])){
                    $return .= renderPosts($post['children'], $tmpModel);
                }

                $return .= '</li>';
        }
        $return .= '</ul>';

        return $return;
    } ?>

    <? $tmpModel = $this->Html; // we have to pass html helper inside, I am not sure it this is best way but it works
    echo renderPosts($posts, $tmpModel); //finally, we render the $result returned. ?>

</div>
```